# I can't return new observable looks like doesn't work

Tags: angular, observable

I am hagving problems with Observables

I have next code:

```
 public save(): any {
        var that = this;
        try {
            debugger;//1
            return  new Observable((observer) => {        
                observer.next("123");

                debugger; //2
            })
        } catch (e) {
            debugger; //3

        }
    }
```

I am importing next modules:

```
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
```

Debugging it stops in **debugger: //1** but never in **debugger; //2**

I tried with:
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

component is:

```
save().subscribe(res => {
    debugger; //4
});
```

but nothing. It doesnt stop in **debugger //4**

what is wrong? It should stop at **debugger //2;** and **//4**

I am using angular 8

Comment: Where is your code where you subscribe to the observable?

Comment: I added it that information

Comment: Now where is the code in component.ts? When is it executed? Post a complete minimal example in a stackblitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to understand about observables is that they are "lazy". Unless you subscribe to an observable, it doesn't emit any values.

Since your `save` method returns an `observable`. For you to invoke debugger 2, you'll have to subscribe to the return.

e.g.

```
someMethod() {
  const saved = this.save();
  saved.subscribe(() => {
    // debugger 2 will be invoked ...
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuz you already nexted the stream (observer.next("123")).

So plz changed position like below.

```
public save(): any {
        var that = this;
        try {
            debugger;//1
            return  new Observable((observer) => { 
                debugger; //2

                observer.next("123");
            })
        } catch (e) {
            debugger; //3

        }
    }
```